# Pass value to uWSGI from Django application

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, nginx, uwsgi

How can I pass the `request.user.username` to the uWSGI logger from Django?

I want to generate the below log:

```
[pid: 1|app: 0|req: 2/38] **REQUEST.USER.USERNAME**
```

Also, I'm using Nginx as the webserver.